# Building an array of files in a directory

Tags: java, arrays, file

How is this done in Java? I wish to create an array of fileNames to output in a program, the files will be the ones in my home directory.

So far I have :

```
File[] fileList = new File(user.home).listFiles()
```

Is this all I need ?

And then, to print out those files, can I just do :

```
int i = 0;
while (fileList.getNext() != null) {
System.out.println(filelist[i]
i++
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you trying to print the contents of each file? If so you'll need to use the Reader classes in the java.io package.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are right on.  I've put together your code bit more cleanly.

```
File[] fileList = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles();
        for (int i=0;i < fileList.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(fileList[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

More or less yes, but you need to check that file is a file not a directory of course if you need only files names.

```
public static String[] fileNames(String directoryPath) {

    File dir = new File(directoryPath);

    Collection<String> files  =new ArrayList<String>();

    if(dir.isDirectory()){
        File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles();

        for(File file : listFiles){
            if(file.isFile()) {
                files.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    return files.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's how we get the list of file from local directory. Please note that the listFiles() will also include directories. So if you are interested only in files then you got to check isFile() on each file. If you are interested to get selective file user FileFilter.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your file list fetching to this

```
File[] fileList = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest way by which you can build array of files present in your home directory. And using the loop, you can get the name of all files very easily. Here is the code:

```
  // Building array of files.
    File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

  // Iterating array of files for printing name of all files present in the directory.
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("File Name: " +listOfFiles[i]);
    }
```