# Java - Run Method on Each File Using An Array of File Names

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to run a method based on an array of filenames?  For example, I wish to create an array of all files within a given directory - which [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259872/building-an-array-of-files-in-a-directory) question discusses - but I then wish to apply a method to all files/filenames within the array.

The reason for this is because I have 300 (soon-to-be 500) image files which I wish to perform a function on, and it is clearly ridiculous to have to write 300-500 separate instances of the same function in the `main()` method for many obvious reasons (also, the number of images is likely to increase in the future, which would definitely make this approach even more ludicrous).

I would therefore like to know if this can be done using an array to store the file names, and then using the file name from each array location `0-299` in order to perform the function on said image file.

Something like this:

```
Create array of FileNames;

For
    all filenames 0-299 in array;
    perform method(filename(0-299));
End for
```

I have already written the relevant code to perform the function, I just need to know if there is a way of achieving my goal in a much more efficient manner.

A simpler way of putting this is to ask how to run a method on all files (not sub-directories) within a given directory?

Many thanks.

Comment: Lets see the relevant  code that that you have written so far. I think that's the only way to really understand what you are saying.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html ? with vashs answer from the link you posted.

Comment: I can in fact confirm that this is not homework and is, in fact, a private piece of work that I am working on for my own benefit.  For those of you who have made that assumption, I can only inform you that you are incorrect.  With regards to the code in question, that can be considered neither here nor there - my question is merely enquiring as to how to go about implementing something regardless of what code is going to be used, whether it is my own method, or a simple `System.out.print("Text");` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void processFiles() {
    File dir = new File("/tmp/");
       if (dir.isDirectory()) {
          final File[] files = dir.listFiles();
          for (File file : files) {
             myMethod(file);
          }
       }
}

private void myMethod(File file) {
   // do what you need here with the file
}
```

Comment: maybe someone has noticed missing opening brace ;-)

Comment: but still - that should not be a reason for down-voting since your answer is good

Answer (score 1):

First of all using [Java Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) is the preferred way to work with collections in Java.

Java Collections are easy to iterate - you can use the enhanced [For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for that: `for(File f : collectionOfFiles) { ... }`

Inside this enhanced for-each loop you will just need to call the method doing whatever you want it to do with your files.